# jQuery event handler continues working after element no longer matches selector

Tags: jquery

I have a button that is disabled on page load. Later on I remove the "disabled" attribute from the button via Javascript. Clicking the button does not result in any event however despite the element no longer matching these selectors. Why?

Here is my HTML & JS for the button on page load:

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Submit</button>
```

JS

```
$("btn[disabled]).click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: It just occurred to me that maybe an event handler is attached according to the selectors on page load. Then once the element no longer matches the selectors, it doesn't matter since the event handler is already attached. How should I have done this instead?

Comment: @ Donny P: Right. If you want to do the other, you can use event delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you bind an event to an element the changes done to the element attributes after that will not get reflected in the registered handlers.

You need to use event delegation to work with dynamic selectors - but in this case propagation cannot be prevented

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn[disabled]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

or check hte condition within the handler

```
$('.btn').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).is('[disabled]')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code has the missing `.` and `"`:

```
$(".btn[disabled]").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The reason it keeps firing the `click` event is that it matched the selector *when you hooked it up*. The code above does this:

1. `$(".btn[disabled]")` - Find all matching elements *at that moment in time*
2. `.click(...)` - Attach a handler to them

If you change them later so they no longer match the selector, it doesn't matter; you've attached the event to the *element*.

You can use event delegation if you want to check the selector when the event occurs:

```
$("some container element").on("click", ".btn[disabled]", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

...where `$("some container element")` matches a container that the `.btn[disabled]` might be in. The click is hooked on the container, but jQuery will only call your handler if the click passed through something matching the selector when it occurred.

You can use `document` as the container (`$(document).on(...)`) if you don't have anything suitable that's a nearer ancestor to the element(s) you want to handle.